# 'GADURewardedInterstitialAd.h' file not found -error xcode-

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-errors, admob

Recently I tried to build my `xcode` project from `Unity3D` export, but after 400/500 tasks, a major error appear:

> GADURewardedInterstitialAd.h file not found

I've tried:

- restart xcode
- re import GoogleMobileAds SDK IOS(latest update 8.7.0)
- change admob version in Unity (5.4.0 or 6.0)
- sure, cleaning the project (before launch "archive")
- remove the "GoogleMobileAds.xcframework" from "Frameworks" folder and add it again
- try the method "framework search paths" in Build Setting (UnityFramework)
- try to YES (Enable Modules C & Objective-C)
- try to modify architecture (why not)
- try to add in OTHER LINKER FLAGS "-ObjC"

No luck, still the same error, any ideas to solve this? thanks.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

My solution to various errors of this type was to import the GoogleMobileAds via CocoaPods and not manually. This is because first of all it does everything by itself, and then because it installs you in the project the version of the GMA of iOS supported by the unity plugin (or else sometimes you may find yourself with the version of the unity plugin that does not support the too recent version of the package for iOS)

I suggest you try initially with version 5.4.0 of the plugin, as 6.0.0 and 6.0.1 I saw on GMA's GitHub that some users encounter various errors on Xcode, then maybe if it works you can try with a plugin most recent. What version of Unity do you use? (I built with 2020.3)

I leave you the links of two of my videos that I made that explain (1) how to install/update CocoaPods, (2) how to import GMA via CocoaPods.
I want to say that I have no intention of advertising my content, I have a tiny channel with some videos to help those like me who have had various problems starting to program or use Unity, I do not monetize. You are obviously free to look for information on the internet regarding what was said before and not to watch the videos, which I repeat I have linked only to help.

(1)
[Install/update CocoaPods](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rosxmZWx0ps)   ,
(2)
[Import GMA using CocoaPods](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WyErxwr8Rc4)

In this other link (which leads to a documentation page of the GMA package for iOS), you can read the note from Google that suggests the use of CocoaPods:
[Link](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/download)